# Can I validate and submit a form by a hyperlink control in C#.net?

Tags: asp.net, html, hyperlink, form-submit

Possible to use a link control to validate and submit a form? What would be the code to tie the click event of the link control to the submission functions? (I prefer link buttons much more than input buttons for styling across browsers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a control built in for this: [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx?ppud=4).

Instead of `<asp:Button />` use `<asp:LinkButton />` to render an `<a ... />` link, style it as you wish :)

You use it the same way as you do a [`Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx?ppud=4) control, assign a handler to it's `OnClick` event, etc, whatever you need to do.  The handling from your code's perspective is *very* similar, identical in most cases.